# Promise Chain Within a for-each Loop Inside a .then() of Another Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, synchronization, es6-promise

In JavaScript, I'm calling a promise which returns an id; we'll call this `promise1`. promise1 has a following `.then()` which, given the id returned from promise1, calls a for-each loop. On each iteration of this loop, `promise2` is carried out

promsie2 *also* has a `.then()`. so the data returned from promise2 can be utilized.

**mycode.js**

```
exports.my_function = (req, res) => {
    var data = req.body;
    var name_array = ["Jeff", "Sophie", "Kristen"]
    var personal_ID_arr = []
    
    promise1.getID(data)    //promise1 gets an int 'id'
       .then(id => {
          array.forEach(name => {      //for each name
              promise2.getPersonalID(name, id)    //promise2 creates a personal id for each person using their name and the id generated from promise1
                  .then(personalID => {
                      personal_ID_arr.push(personalID)  //add the generated personal id to an arr
                   })
           })
        })

   //will need to operate on 'personal_ID_arr' here after the above finishes or possibly still within the promise1's .then; as long as the arr is filled fully
 }
```

However, I'm running into the issue of synchronicity not allowing for this type of logic to happen, as things begin happening out of order once it gets to the loop aspect of the program. I need to carry out another function with the filled-out 'personal_ID_arr' after these promises are carried out as well

I've looked at other questions regarding promise chaining but this is a different case due to the fact the for loop needs to work with the data from the first promise and use .then() inside a .then(). Surely, I don't need to keep this structure though if a better one exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you would want to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) here.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping an array of IDs that an asynchronous operation will fill, is not something that will help you carrying out more asynchronous operations on the array later. Instead, consider using an array of Promises for each name, and wait them all to resolve using Promise.all. Also, i removed the personal_ID_arr from the function my_function variables and moved it to the appropriate asynchronous operation. I did a simple console log of the array, you should fill your next step there.

Although maybe you need to write this logic with Promises, but I would suggest using async / await for this task, it will lead to more readable code.

```
exports.my_function = (req, res) => {
var data = req.body;
var name_array = ["Jeff", "Sophie", "Kristen"]

promise1.getID(data)    //promise1 gets an int 'id'
   .then(id =>
      //map the array of Strings to array of Promises instead, wait for them to resolve
      Promise.all(name_array.map(name =>      
          promise2.getPersonalID(name, id) 
       ))
    )
    .then(personal_ID_arr => console.log(personal_ID_arr))


 //will need to operate on 'personal_ID_arr' here after the above finishes or possibly still within the promise1's .then; as long as the arr is filled fully
 }
```